# How can I pair lowest key and lowest value together(it should be rising by order small to big)?

Tags: python, dictionary

```py
{'1': 30, '2': 15, '4': 29, '11': 22, '12': 41, '14': 26}
```

in this dict, how can i pair lowest key and lowest value together(it should be rising by order small to big)?
Comment ur answer.

Comment: What have you tried do far? Please add some sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do in this way:

Take out the keys and values

```
keys=[k for k in d.keys()]
values = [v for v in d.values()]
```

create new dict

```
values.sort()
keys.sort()
new_dict= dict(zip(keys,values))
```

Output:

```
{'1': 15, '11': 22, '12': 26, '14': 29, '2': 30, '4': 41}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use builtin function `min`.
(You don't need to sort).

```py
dic = {'1': 30, '2': 15, '4': 29, '11': 22, '12': 41, '14': 26}
result = {min(dic): min(dic.values())}
print(result)
```

output:

```py
{'1': 15}
```

Answer (score 2):

here is a more compact way:

```
d = {'1': 30, '2': 15, '4': 29, '11': 22, '12': 41, '14': 26}

dict(zip(*map(sorted, (d, d.values()))))
```

output:

```
{'1': 15, '11': 22, '12': 26, '14': 29, '2': 30, '4': 41}
```

Comment: I don't know why they do it,there are lot of questions where people just write expected output and they answered it without asking for their method

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {'1': 30, '2': 15, '4': 29, '11': 22, '12': 41, '14': 26}
print(dict(zip(sorted(a.keys(), key=lambda x:int(x)), sorted(a.values()))))
# {'1': 15, '2': 22, '4': 26, '11': 29, '12': 30, '14': 41}
```